# one big or more small objects in html5 local storage

Tags: html, local-storage

is it better to store one big JSON object in local storage and append into it other data or use multiple small objects with datas in it? I would like to use it as history storage for any some application (so I think 5MB is enough).
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the way you want to access your data:
If you want to access small parts of your data once in a while, you should put it into small objects. I did a couple of performance test a while ago and found the lookup of on objects in  a localStorage filled with a lot of objects quit fast. If you use small objects, you might use less memory because you don't have to read and parse a big json object.
On the other side, keep in mind that reading localStorage is a blocking function. So if you need to iterate over the object, i might block your whole browser. In that case, it might be better to save the data in a huge chunck and read it at once.

Comment: "save the data in a huge chunck and read it at once" +1 for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly easier to call on one function and one item like so

```
localStorage.setItem('JSON', '{"whole":[{"lotta":"json"}],"data":"here"}');
```

you can also use `localStorage` like a regular object like so:

```
localStorage['JSON'] = '{"whole":[{"lotta":"json"}],"data":"here"}';
```

but either way you'll have to parse the JSON and run functions against it etc.

It really depends on how much history you want to store, and how you want to store it.

Also `localStorage` persists between visits, if you only need to keep the history during the current visit you can use `sessionStorage` exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use it with more small objects, and I'm using the [CarboStorage](http://carbogrid.com/index.php/storage/home) library for that, which is a wrapper around localStorage.